# UIAutomator and Android Image Gallery

Tags: android, ui-automation, android-uiautomator

I am testing my Android app with UIAutomator which works fine for the most screens.

My App opens the Android Images Gallery and the user has to select an image. So I am able to open the Image Gallery with UIAutomator but I am stuck with selecting the image. Here you can see the screenshot of uiautomatorviewer. How can I pick an image (e.g. the first one) from Image Gallery? Am I missing something?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gallery 3D does not create a View per image but handles the images inside a single custom View, which is the one you are seeing.
To pick an image you may click using screen coordinates, not ideal though.

Comment: quite painful to implement :(

Comment: [AndroidViewClient/culebra](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient) and [CulebraTester](http://culebra.dtmilano.com/) can reduce your pain ;-)

Answer (score 0):

you can try ui automator content description function.to search for with "jpeg " and perform a click.